# Putting object to S3 using java but didn't see any object from the console

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have tried the following code to put a string into the S3. I saw the folder was created under the bucket but didn't see any object in the folder. What am I missing?

```
String SUFFIX = "/";

try 
{
    s3client.putObject(bucketName, today.toString() + SUFFIX + source + SUFFIX, "abc");
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I don't think it is a permission issue, because I have those folders created by above code and there is no exception caught by the try-catch also.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uploading it without trailing slash? If path ends with it, then from S3 point of view it is really a directory, not a particular file. So, trimming that slash should work

Comment: @RandomGuy, you are 100% right. Please turn your comment to an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Amazon S3 folders documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html):

> The Amazon S3 console treats all objects that have a forward slash (`/`) character as the last (trailing) character in the key name as a folder, for example `examplekeyname/`. You can't upload an object that has a key name with a trailing `/` character using the Amazon S3 console.
>
> However, you can upload objects that are named with a trailing `/` with the Amazon S3 API by using the AWS CLI, AWS SDKs, or REST API.
>
> An object that is **named with a trailing "/" appears as a folder** in the Amazon S3 console.

So, in your case, removing trailing slash should do the work:

```java
String SUFFIX = "/";
try {
    s3client.putObject(bucketName, today.toString() + SUFFIX + source, "abc");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```